# Decimal Separator From Control Panel Customize Setting

Tags: .net, vb.net

I create an application with VB.NET

As instructed in MSDN I've changed Culture to en-US. **It works** to override decimal separator to *dot* if user sets regional format to whatever language with *comma* separator.

```
Public Sub New()

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("en-US")

    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

**Now the problem is**, how can I override decimal separator if user changed system's decimal separator from Control Panel > Region And Language > Additional Settings (in Format tab)?

CultureInfo is not able to override those custom settings. I need to override all the comma decimal separator to dot without using replace string function.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`NumberFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `CultureInfo`:

```
Dim myCI As New CultureInfo("en-US", False)
myCI.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture
   = myCI
```